# How to convert csv to parquet using pandas?

Tags: pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow, python-polars

I want to convert my CSV file to a parquet file. My code below causes my kernel to be KILLED regardless of the `chunksize` parameter. I do not know the number of rows x columns in my file, but I suspect that I have many columns.
What is the ideal solution?

With Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

csv_file = "kipan_exon.csv.gz"
parquet_file = "kipan_exon.csv.gz"
chunksize = 1000000

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="\t", chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False, compression="gzip")    

for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    print("Chunk", i)
    if i == 0:
        parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk).schema
        parquet_writer = pd.ParquetWriter(parquet_file, parquet_schema, compression="gzip")
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)
    parquet_writer.write_table(table)

parquet_writer.close()
```

With dask:

```
df = dd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="\t", compression="gzip", blocksize=None)
df = df.repartition(partition_size="100MB")
df.to_parquet(parquet_file, write_index=False)
```

Comment: I suppose your dataframe is too big to hold in memory. Therefore, pandas is not ideal approach. I think the best approach is to use a tool like `dask`, which has the same interface as pandas. Does it have to pandas only?

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Do you get a memory error? Is the process killed? Does it just take forever? Or is there a different error?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work to me, except do you know your two files have the same name? The chunking strategy is a good one - there’s no reason why pandas wouldn’t be able to handle this as long as chunksize is sufficiently small. so curious about the actual error. the dask solution would look something like `dask.dataframe.read_csv(csv_file, blocksize="100MB").to_parquet(parquet_file)`.

Comment: The process is KILLED with both pandas and parquet.

Comment: Can you read in just one chunk without writing to parquet? Try to break this down to identify where the problem is.

Comment: I'm able to execute `df = dd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="\t", compression="gzip", blocksize=None)`. The process is killed at the subsequent step when writing to parquet.

Comment: Alternatively, can I convert my txt file directly to parquet or tsv using command line?

Answer (score 1):

Another (more recent) solution is to use a `LazyFrame` approach in [`polars`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet):

```py
csv_file = "kipan_exon.csv"  # this doesn't work with compressed files right now
parquet_file = "kipan_exon.parquet"  # @MichaelDelgado's comment re: same value as `csv_file`

from polars import scan_csv
ldf = scan_csv(csv_file)
ldf.sink_parquet(parquet_file)
```

This should work well in memory-constrained situations since the data is not loaded fully, but streamed to the parquet file.

Comment: This code raised `Illegal instruction` error.

Comment: Interesting, could you check if this thread applies to you? (old cpu) https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2922

Comment: Alternatively, can I convert my txt file directly to parquet or tsv using the command line? My CPU is not old

Comment: To be precise, my data is from http://firebrowse.org/?cohort=KIPAN&download_dialog=true and the file is `illuminahiseq_rnaseqv2-exon_quantification (MD5)`.  I untar this file and want to read it as a dataframe, preferably using pandas.

Comment: You probably have an old cpu. Try installing `polars-lts-cpu`

Comment: I tried `polars-lts-cpu`. Cant' use `scan_csv` because it raises `exceptions.ComputeError: cannot scan compressed csv; use read_csv for compressed data`. I tried `polars.read_csv` and the process is killed.

Comment: Ah, well, decompressing the file might do the trick.

Comment: I'm now able to save the file as parquet, thank you. However, I'm unable to read the file as tab-separated.

Answer (score 0):

When using `dask` for csv to parquet conversion, I'd recommend avoiding `.repartition`. It introduces additional data shuffling that can strain workers and the scheduler. The simpler approach would look like this:

```py
csv_file = "kipan_exon.csv.gz"
parquet_file = "kipan_exon.parquet"  # @MichaelDelgado's comment re: same value as `csv_file`

from dask.dataframe import read_csv
df = read_csv(csv_file, sep="\t", compression="gzip")
df.to_parquet(parquet_file, write_index=False)
```

Comment: Process killed even without partition.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but hard to debug...